# Lower Power Inductive Heating Circuit Design Questions

Tags: design, temperature, low-power, constraints

I'm trying to design a very low power (<=10W) inductive heating circuit that will heat the work material to 40-50degC. I've seen plenty of Royer Oscillator circuits online (see here: http://www.rmcybernetics.com/images/induction-heater-schematic.jpg) but how can the temperature output be configured in the circuit? Also, I want to make the power draw as low as possible. What are some parameters I can play with to achieve these design constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the power draw will be pretty dependent on how much power you're dumping into your load, varying the supply voltage would be a pretty simple way of regulating the power output of a resonant circuit.